# Prestashop error "invalid security token"

Tags: php, security, module, prestashop

im creating a new module for prestashop 1.5.6 and im having some problems with it.

The module has to send sms to the costumers and it has to be an option of the back-Office menu.

I have created the module with the install and uninstall functions and added the tabs to the `back-office` menu, but im a newbie in `prestashop` so i don´t know how to make the `AdminMyModuleController.php` and when i try to click the tab of the module it says `"INVALID SECURITY TOKEN"`, i don´t know how resolve this issue because i don´t know much of security.

If someone can add me on facebook or whatever to help me would be amazing.

Here is the code of the mymodule.php:

private function _createTab()
  {

```
// Tab Raiz

   $data = array(
              'id_tab' => '', 
              'id_parent' => 0, 
              'class_name' => 'Empty', 
              'module' => 'mymodule', 
              'position' => 14, 'active' => 1 
             );

/* Insert the data to the tab table*/
$res = Db::getInstance()->insert('tab', $data);

//Get last insert id from db which will be the new tab id
$id_tabP = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

//Define tab multi language data
    $data_lang = array(
                     'id_tab' => $id_tabP, 
                     'id_lang' => Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),
                     'name' => 'SMS a clientes'
                     );

```
// Now insert the tab lang data
$res &= Db::getInstance()->insert('tab_lang', $data_lang);

// Tab Configuracion

$data = array(
              'id_tab' => '', 
              'id_parent' => $id_tabP, 
              'class_name' => 'AdminMymodule', 
              'module' => 'mymodule', 
              'position' => 1, 'active' => 1 
             );

$res = Db::getInstance()->insert('tab', $data);
$id_tab = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
$data_lang = array(
                 'id_tab' => $id_tab, 
                 'id_lang' => Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),
                 'name' => 'Configuracion'
                 );
$res &= Db::getInstance()->insert('tab_lang', $data_lang);

// Tab Enviar Sms

$data = array(
              'id_tab' => '', 
              'id_parent' => $id_tabP, 
              'class_name' => 'AdminEnviar', 
              'module' => 'mymodule', 
              'position' => 1, 'active' => 1 
             );


$res = Db::getInstance()->insert('tab', $data);
$id_tab = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();

$data_lang = array(
                 'id_tab' => $id_tab, 
                 'id_lang' => Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'),
                 'name' => 'Enviar SMS'
                 );

$res &= Db::getInstance()->insert('tab_lang', $data_lang);

return true;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some code to show us so we can help you ? What information did you enter to create the tab (Name, Class, Module) ?

Comment: @blobmarket i have mymodule.php with this code:

Comment: @blobmarket, Sorry im newbie in stackoverflow, i edited my post so you can see the _createTab() function, thank you very much by the way

Answer (score 1):

As Lliw said, you must use InstallModuleTab function.

```
private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent)
{
    $pass = true;
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->name = $tabName;
    $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
    $tab->module = $this->name;  // defined in __construct() function
    $tab->id_parent = $idTabParent;
    $pass = $tab->save();

    return($pass);
}
```

You can put all in your Install function. For example for your first tab:

```
public function install()
{
    if(!parent::install()
        || !$this->installModuleTab('Empty', array(1 => 'SMS a clientes'), $idTabParent = 0))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

You can set languages with the following array:

```
array(1 => 'SMS a clientes', 2 => 'Language 2', 3 => 'Language 3')
```

Then you must create the AdminMyModuleController.php file

Answer (score 0):

It's the wrong way to create a module tab. You should use this function in your install() :

```
$this->installModuleTab('AdminMyModule', array(1 => 'Attribute description'), $idTabParent = 9);
```

Then create an AdminMyModuleController.php in your module folder/controllers/admin/AdminMyModuleController.php

But you will need to set some function to see something displayed, i'll make a tutorial for that but until i do it, you can look in another admincontroller from the prestashop core and do the same.